# Why does my timer in swift keep speeding up?

Tags: swift, timer

I am creating a trivia app in swift and I have a timer that counts down each question. However as the user progresses with each question the timer speeds up. Can someone help me fix this?

My runGameTimer function:

```
func runGameTimer()
{
    gameTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(RockTriviaViewController.updateGameTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}
```

My updateGameTimer function:

```
@objc func updateGameTimer()
{
    gameInt -= 1
    timerLabel.text = String(gameInt)
    if (gameInt == 0)
    {
        gameTimer.invalidate()
      /*
        if (currentQuestion != rockQuestions[questionSet].count)
        {
            newQuestion()
        }
        else
        {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "showRockScore", sender: self)
        }
       */
    }
}
```

Where I call my code:

```
func newQuestion()
{
    gameInt = 11
    runGameTimer()
    rockQuestion.text = rockQuestions[questionSet][currentQuestion]
    rightAnswerPlacement = arc4random_uniform(3)+1
    var Button: UIButton = UIButton()
    var x = 1

    for i in 1...3
    {
        Button = view.viewWithTag(i) as! UIButton
        if(i == Int(rightAnswerPlacement))
        {
            Button.setTitle(rockAnswers[questionSet][currentQuestion][0], for: .normal)
        }
        else
        {
            Button.setTitle(rockAnswers[questionSet][currentQuestion][x], for: .normal)
            x = 2
        }
    }

    currentQuestion += 1
}
```

Comment: How often do you call `runGameTimer`? From the sounds of it, you are creating multiple timers

Comment: I figured that was it. I call it every time the user presses the submit button and it generates a new question. I added my code to the post if you wanna check it out. I still need help changing it

Comment: `invalidate` the current instance of `Timer` before creating a new one

Comment: I believe Im doing that in my updateGameTimer function. Maybe I'm doing it wrong. Please take look. I just posted it

Comment: Check this link to understand how to use timer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46792784/4311935

Comment: @MadProgrammer In what function would I add `invalidate.Timer` right now it's in my `updateGameTimer` function

Comment: @AlexTănăsescu I would `invalidate` when it's no longer need.  If it's not optional, then would also possibly mean call `invalidate` when before you create a new one as well (otherwise simply check to see if it's non-null)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling `runGameTimer()` in every call to `newQuestion()`. If a timer was already running then you'll add a new timer each time, and they will all call your selector. So if you have 3 timers running, your selector will be called 3x as often. That's not what you want.

Change your timer variable to be `weak`:

```
weak var gameTimer: Timer?
```

And then in runGameTimer invalidate the timer before creating a new one, using optional chaining:

```
func runGameTimer() {
    gameTimer?.invalidate() //This will do nothing if gameTimer is nil.
                            //it will also cause the gameTimer to be nil since it's weak.

    gameTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(RockTriviaViewController.updateGameTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```

By making the game timer weak it will get set to nil as soon as it's invalidated. (When you schedule a timer the system retains it while it is running so it stays valid as long as it continues to run.)

By using optional chaining to reference the timer:

```
gameTimer?.invalidate()
```

The code doesn't do anything if gameTimer is nil.

Comment: If my answer solved your problem then you should accept it. Once you have the reputation, up-voting useful answers is also considered good form, but optional.

Comment: Just did. It says its recorded but not publicly displayed because of my reputation

Comment: Upvoted your answer. How do you accept it? Sorry I just started

Comment: Yup, you did now. For future reference, you click the check mark to accept an answer, and the up-arrow to up-vote an answer (You need more reputation points to up-vote answers. I believe accepting answers gives you reputation points.)